# React-hot-loader with material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hot-loader

i use in my project [@material-ui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui) and [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader).

Hot loader works fine, but if i use material-ui modules, it not works.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete'; // TODO

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      text
    </div>
  );
};

export default hot(module)(App);
```

May be, someone know, why? What i need for a correct working? It problem only with @material-ui.
Thanks you for attention!

Comment: I created two issues:
[material-ui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12160) и 
[webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1443)

Comment: I have the same issue, seems material-ui does not pick up the `@hot-reloader/react-dom` alias. I get an error that react-dom can't be found with the material-ui components

Comment: @Dmitriy, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584315/webpack-dev-server-doesnt-watch-recompile-files-if-they-import-named-exports
Maybe it will help.